# How can I create an Action delegate from MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, action, methodinfo

I want to get an action delegate from a MethodInfo object. Is this possible?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use [Delegate.CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6.aspx):

```
// Static method
Action action = (Action) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), method);

// Instance method (on "target")
Action action = (Action) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), target, method);
```

For an `Action<T>` etc, just specify the appropriate delegate type everywhere.

In .NET Core, `Delegate.CreateDelegate` doesn't exist, but `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` does:

```
// Static method
Action action = (Action) method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));

// Instance method (on "target")
Action action = (Action) method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), target);
```

Comment: Upvoted. How to apply this to DataEventArgs<T> ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376326/how-to-create-generic-event-delegate-from-methodinfo

Comment: `Delegate.CreateDelegate` does not appear to be available in .Net Core. Any ideas there?

Comment: @IAbstract: Interesting - I hadn't spotted that. You can call `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` instead. (Just tried it, and it worked fine.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: yeah, actually found that and appreciate adding to answer. +1 for completeness!!!

Comment: @JonSkeet [side-bar & food for thought] re: Delegate vs MethodInfo in `try-catch` blocks.

I discovered the much perturbing failure of try-catch blocks when invoking a MethodInfo (e.g., obtained via reflection). However, if a delegate is created from the MethodInfo and cast to a `Delegate` sub-class - i.e., Action, Func - and executed in a try-catch block, any exceptions are caught as expected.

Comment: @IAbstract: That sounds very odd. Possibly ask about it in a new question?

Comment: Can a parameter be passed into this delegate?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: Not an `Action`, no. If you want a delegate with an argument, pick a delegate with a signature matching what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work on top of John's advice too:

```
public static class GenericDelegateFactory
{
    public static object CreateDelegateByParameter(Type parameterType, object target, MethodInfo method) {

        var createDelegate = typeof(GenericDelegateFactory).GetMethod("CreateDelegate")
            .MakeGenericMethod(parameterType);

        var del = createDelegate.Invoke(null, new object[] { target, method });

        return del;
    }

    public static Action<TEvent> CreateDelegate<TEvent>(object target, MethodInfo method)
    {
        var del = (Action<TEvent>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TEvent>), target, method);

        return del;
    }
}
```